# Android: Why can I not setText in the same line as findViewById

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am not sure if this is an Android issue or a AndroidStudio issue. Why is this valid:

```
TextView currentItem
currentItem = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText);
currentItem.setText("text");
```

But this is not (cannot resolve method setText(Java.Lang.String))

```
(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText).setText("text");
```

Not a big deal, but I have some code that requires a lot of text updates. It would be much cleaner if I could get this in one line.

Comment: Try sticking another pair of parentheses around `(TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText)`

Comment: Just remember, method invocations have higher precedence than casts. You'll need extra parentheses if you want to cast in the middle of a series of chained method calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`findViewById` returns a generic '`View`', hence you have to cast it to `TextView` before you can set the text. In your piece of code you are trying to invoke setText on the 'View' object rather than the 'TextView' object.

Try this :

```
 ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText)).setText("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this please :

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText)).setText("text");
```

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` returns a `View`, so you don't have `setText` from `TextView` yet. You have to cast first to `TextView` by putting parenthesis around `findViewById` and then call `setText` like this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.myText)).setText("text");
```

Also, this is a Java thing, not Android nor Android Studio thing.