# Can't able to use setText() method in same line as findViewById(R.id.textView)

Tags: java, android, view

I can't able to use `findViewById('R.id.textView').setText("message")` in my code, Android studio shows this error

> Cannot resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)

It is not the same as this question [Android: Why can I not setText in the same line as findViewById](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025596/android-why-can-i-not-settext-in-the-same-line-as-findviewbyid) as in updated android versions we no longer need to do casting for `findViewById()` method, for more details see this question [No need to cast the result of findViewById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid)

Above all, the same code works if I save the result of `findViewById` in a variable first(Without casting it to TextView manually) i.e

```
   TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);
    textview.setText("message");
```

Above code works fine, if findViewById returns `View` object then it should also not work, and if it returns `TextView` object then one linear code `findViewById('R.id.textView').setText("message")` should work as well.

I know if I cast it in TextView then it will work. but my question is why do I need to cast if it already returns TextView object?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast `textview`  to `TextView`:

```
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("message")
```

Comment: thanks, but why do i need to cast if it already returns `TextView` object?

Comment: The compiler does not know that the view will be a TextView.

Comment: This is why if you first do this: `TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textview);` the compiler will have no problem to do next: `textview.setText("message");`

Answer (score 3):

You need to cast the view into a `TextView`

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText("message")
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your example works is because static type assignment (through the variable declaration and assignment) promises that the object will be a TextView, which indeed does have the setText() method, or a runtime exception will occur.

setText() isn't defined in the View class, so directly calling it on a method returning a View object results in an exception because the compiler only knows the method doesn't exist in the returned View object. Parents aren't inferred as a child instance. You as the developer check or explicitly state it (casting or variable declaration and assignment)

An explicit cast on findViewById() to TextView adds the "promise" that the object will be a class with the method defined, so it'll compile.

Answer (score 0):

Is this in a `Fragment`? If so, make sure you are using the `view` passed within `onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`. Something like this:

```
view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview).setText("message")
```

Granted my answer is written in Kotlin, but you should be able to transpose to Java with ease. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: hi, thanks for answering,   the previous answer solved my problem, thanks anyway:)